# PC does not boot into Windows, but Ubuntu still works well; how to recover?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader, reboot, boot-repair

I installed 7 operating systems in my PC. All worked very well. (Ubuntu 11, Ubuntu 14, EduBoss, Redhat6, Nodezero, Windows 8, Win 7). I frequently used Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14 last 6-7 months, I enjoy all operating system but one day after CHKDSK perform by Win7 my PC was unable to start with windows boot. If I try to start windows PC restarts very fast and shows nothing to any options just restart.

All other Linux O.S.  work but no any other Win boot is working.
As per my knowledge I guesses that problem occurred by file corruption or by CHKDSK operation by Windows.

Can I repair Windows boot option by Linux? (without win bootable disk)

- Architect i386
- 2 Gb ram
- Intel quad core
- OS. First I installed windows and then Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the methods using Linux is to use **fsck.msdos** command which is found majorly in most of the Linux Distributions. While you've not mentioned that is there any error shown by Windows and, it is not mentioned too whether it is possible to boot into **Safe Mode** by pressing and holding **Shift** and tapping **F8** repeatedly. Based on the dearth of information here, I advise booting into Linux, open the Terminal, and type:

> - **`sudo fsck.msdos /dev/XYZ`** where XYZ is the partition where Windows is installed(say sda1).
>
> There are many parameters available which can be accessed by typing `fsck.msdos -h` but the basic command should be able to correct your Windows.

If that went well, you will want to check whether Linux is able to detect Windows loader now or not. Besides, you need to generate a new GRUB configuration file too. I'm assuming the Linux you're booted into is running Grub 2.0. To Probe the Boot Loader, type the command:

- **`sudo os-probe`**, it shall give you an output like this:

> /dev/sda1:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain

If you receive any such output, you can go ahead for building new Grub configuration file. In Terminal, type:

> - **`sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`**, if your **grub.cfg** is at some other location then replace the path in the command with your file location.
> - Type **`sudo grub-install /dev/sda`** where **sda** is my primary HDD having Windows and Linux installed.

Reboot, and choose Windows in Grub Menu. it should boot. If it doesn't we can try other methods but your question demands only Linux-specific solution.

Comment: madhavnikam@madhavnikam-Aspire-E5-511:~$ sudo fsck.msdos /dev/sda2
fsck.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
Currently, only 1 or 2 FATs are supported, not 0.

Comment: sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
Found initrd image:/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
Found linux image:/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image:/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
Found memtest86+image:/boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+image:/boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows8(loader)on /dev/sda1
Found Debian GNU/Linux(7.0)on /dev/sda10
Found RedHatEnterpriseLinuxServerrelease6.4(Santiago) on /dev/sda12
Found Ubuntu11.04(11.04)on /dev/sda14
Found Ubuntu10.04.1LTS(10.04)on /dev/sda8
done

Comment: madhavnikam@madhavnikam-Aspire-E5-511:~$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda6
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `ntfs' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.

Comment: windows boot problem not solve nothing do any new. PC still restart when try to run windows boot loader. But it upgrade GRUB loader with sequence of disk-part. any other solution for it?

Comment: any other idea to solve that? can i repair by using Windows disc ? if by windows disc: can it affect GRUB >? YES then how to recover GRUB? I fail to solve that problem without windows disk. I think it is nearly impossible to solve that problem without windows disk. PLZ tell any other method to solve that.....

Comment: I once mentioned the solution by using both Linux and Windows. Since you want method involving Windows Installation Disk , check [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188128/after-reinstalling-linux-mint-windows-7-does-not-boot/188324#188324) my answer. Look for Windows method in there. And yes, if you try WIndows Installation Disk, you will lose GRUb. But I also mentioned there how to reinstall it and get over with all the issues at once. I hope it helps. Do check the comments in my answer there to lead you better.

Comment: problem solved by win chkdsk thank you dear....

Answer (score 1):

Have you try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool? It seems that your boot files were messed up by CHKDSK.

Comment: i solve this problem by using win disk(both answers are very helpful).thanks problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

1> use win7 disk
2> start up repair 
3> chkdsk >>>> restart 
after restart win boot louder start but GRUB not.
to fix that USE "BOOT-repair" disk and "fsck.msdos" commands. 
both answers are very helpful together.

Comment: friends my answers is depends upon previous two answers.

Comment: above both answers are very useful.

Comment: But it is nearly impossible that you can FIX windows boot problem without windows Boot CD.