# How to recover ubuntu and windows 8 after installing windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

i have a dual boot between ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8 but i installed windows 7 now i cant boot with ubuntu or windows 8 even the grub cant load the three OS's

Comment: reinstall GRUB ... try [boot repair disk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and use above [instructions. for commands](http://askubuntu.com/questions/593722/pc-does-not-boot-into-windows-but-ubuntu-still-works-well-how-to-recover/593727#593727)

Comment: but Grub can show just two  Os isn't it ?

Comment: only windows os show? right?

Comment: it shows jus windows7 and ubuntu but the win8 no it doesnt

Comment: If you have windows 7 disk then boot from disk and use `chkdsk` command it helps you. But at least one time you should try to install GRUB again it better.

Comment: you mean that grub can show 3 os's ???

Comment: Yes! you think right now. and I think you should try it first. you still only guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Windows 7 alongside a pre-existing Ubuntu installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92874/how-do-i-install-windows-7-alongside-a-pre-existing-ubuntu-installation)

Answer (score 0):

Two methods for it.
1) Use windows disk and boot from windows7 disk.
after that
`start up repair` then open `CMD` and type
`chkdsk` then restart PC.

2) Install Grub into Ubuntu (not need any bootable disk)

> - **`sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`**, if your **grub.cfg** is at some other location then replace the path in the command with your file location.
> - Type **`sudo grub-install /dev/sda`** where **sda** is my primary HDD having Windows and Linux installed.

restart PC it solve your problem. I recommends you second method to solve problem.

[my answer source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593722/pc-does-not-boot-into-windows-but-ubuntu-still-works-well-how-to-recover/593727#593727)

Comment: But i'm using ubuntu in a partition and win8 in another one and win 7 also another partition

Comment: @Ȝîmǟd edit your question. what actual happen and what you try? provide details about your problems.

Comment: Look i'll tell you ; i had win 8 and ubuntu ,now i installed win7 to have a tripple boot i did it .now i can run win8 and 7 but ubuntu no ..i tried EasyBcd it shows ubuntu in the boot menu but i cant run it , it cames an error

Comment: can you try my ans?

Comment: look ..first step i can do it but the second no

Comment: first step not work?

Comment: i fix it ...EasyBcd help me a lot