# Can't boot into Ubuntu with dualboot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

This may be the wrong subreddit, but a few hours ago I installed Ubuntu 16.04 to boot alongside windows and I restarted but there is no grub, it just snaps back into Windows 10, every option I found online about did nothing and just goes back into 10.

I have a Gigabyte GA-78lmt-usb3 6.0 motherboard.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZo3g.png

Partition 1 is Windows, Partition 2 is Ubuntu, Partition 3 is swap, Partition 4 is Windows Recovery.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing Grub from a Live session ?

Comment: Use boot repair disk.

Answer (score 1):

[Follow this link and download Boot Repair disk.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) And follow instructions.

 After that use following commands

- `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg,`  if your grub.cfg is at
  some other location then replace the path in the command with your
  file location.
- Type `sudo grub-install` **/dev/sda** where sda is my primary HDD
  having Windows and Linux installed.
  You can run boot repair with your Ubuntu live CD Just type bellow command and follow above grub configuration and installation commands.

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
>  sudo apt-get
>   update
>  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

Source :- [PC does not boot into Windows, but Ubuntu still works well; how to recover?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593722/pc-does-not-boot-into-windows-but-ubuntu-still-works-well-how-to-recover/602148#602148)

Comment: It cannot access the internet, so is the "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair" required?

Comment: @GabeCummings if you not access Internet then use Boot repair disk iso and try from it.